# Why does the clipboard not working on Android

Tags: android, copy, android-webview, clipboard

It works on a web page, but it doesn't work because it's packaged
I'm using Android 13

The code is web page code

````
```
`    copyUrl(){
        if(this.copyUrl){
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                let code = this.$route.query.code
                html2Pdf()
                .from(this.$refs[code]?.$el)
                .set({fileName: 'component.pdf'})
                .output("blob")
                .then(async(pdfDataUri) => {
                    await api.v1.drCoach.post({ pdfDataUri, _pdf: this.$store.state.url});
                    const pdfUrl = `${window.location.origin}/res/pdf/${this.$store.state.url}.pdf`;
                    if (!pdfUrl) return; // url이 정의되어 있지 않으면 함수 종료
                    if (navigator.clipboard) {
                        setTimeout(async () => {
                            console.log(await window.navigator.clipboard.readText());
                            // 클립보드에서 텍스트를 읽어오는지 확인하기 위한 코드
                            // 디버그 목적으로 사용하실 수 있습니다.
                        }, 3000);
                        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(pdfUrl)
                            .then(() => {
                                this.$emit("input", true);
                                this.close();
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                            console.error(`Failed to copy "${pdfUrl}" to clipboard: `, err);
                                this.$emit("input", false);
                            });
                    } 
                    else {
                        this.$copyText(pdfUrl).then(() => {
                            this.$emit("input", true);
                            this.close();
                            console.log("success");
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("PDF 생성 실패: ", error);
                    this.$emit("input", false);
                });
                this.copyUrl=false
            })
        }
    },`
```
````

await window.navigator.clipboard.readText() is Spit out error messages such as 'Uncaught (in prompt) Not AllowedError: Read permission denied.', source: https://~~~'

and navigator.clipboard.writeText(pdfUrl) is Spit out error messages such as 'Failed to copy "https://ww~~" to clipboard:  [object DOMException]", source: https://~~'

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CLIPBOARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CLIPBOARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

I've defined these permissions in AndroidMainfest.xml, but I don't know why they don't work